# Truffle test + Oraclize. Invalid Jump on the second call

Tags: truffle, testrpc, oracles

I'm currently developping an **Ethereum dApp** using *Truffle*, *Test-RPC*, *Oraclize* and *ethereum-bridge*. So at the moment everything is local.

**My issue:** I notice that when I run more than one test calling a function with an Oraclize call, only the first call works. The other ones produce this error:

> Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: invalid JUMP at

---

I simplified my code to make it easier to understand:

**Test-RPC**

Two accounts unlocked with enough ethers.

```
testrpc --account="0x406e31ce4d46beaf4f8f4ccd380de8dccb2eef03e64ffd875b4dfe5e52bf6d84,100000000000000000000" --account="0x13277c2990ed19aeb733c58a4692c9f73ced1d8e3ae4ad3a51d90e02591484b7,100000000000000000000" --secure -u 0 -u 1 --hostname localhost --port 8545
```

**Ethereum-Bridge:**

Using the second account (no 1).

```
node bridge -H localhost:8545 -a 1 --dev
```

**Contract:**

Simple contract with one call to the dummy API *https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1* and the callback stores the json attribute *title*.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.8;

import './OraclizeI.sol';

contract MyContract is usingOraclize  {

    address constant oraclizeOAR = 0x6f485C8BF6fc43eA212E93BBF8ce046C7f1cb475;
    string title;

    modifier onlyOraclize { 
        if (msg.sender != oraclize_cbAddress()) throw; 
        _;
    } 

    function MyContract() {
        OAR = OraclizeAddrResolverI(oraclizeOAR);
    }

    function callOraclize() { 
        oraclize_query("URL", "json(https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1).title");
    }

    function __callback(bytes32 _id, string _result) onlyOraclize {      
        title = _result;
    }

    function getTitle() constant returns (string) {      
        return title;
    }
}
```

**Test**

The test file below contains two identical tests.

```
var MyContract = artifacts.require("./MyContract.sol");

function sleep (time) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, time));
}

contract('MyContract', function(accounts) {
    it("TEST 01", function() {
        return MyContract.deployed().then(function(instance) {
            return instance.callOraclize({from: accounts[0]});
        }).then(function(transaction) {
            return sleep(10000);
        }).then(function() {
            return MyContract.deployed();
        }).then(function(instance) {
            return instance.getTitle.call();
        }).then(function(result) {
            console.log("title="+result);
        });
    });

    it("TEST 02", function() {
        return MyContract.deployed().then(function(instance) {
            return instance.callOraclize({from: accounts[0]});
        }).then(function(transaction) {
            return sleep(10000);
        }).then(function() {
            return MyContract.deployed();
        }).then(function(instance) {
            return instance.getTitle.call();
        }).then(function(result) {
            console.log("title="+result);
        });
    });
});
```

So to conclude, The first one (TEST01) is correctly executed but the second one returns an *Invalid Jump* exception:

[image]

Other Information:

- OS: Windows 8
- truffle version: 3.1
- test-rpc version. 3.0.3
- ethereum-bridge: latest from branch master
- Oraclize (ethereum-api): latest from branch master
- [The code is here](https://github.com/gjeanmart/stackexchange/tree/master/13277)

Comment: Thomas from Oraclize here.

You probably are having this issue because you are not sending any value along. The Oraclize API calls come at a cost, the small fee we charge is paid in advance when calling oraclize_query. The first API call from each contract is free, so this is why your first call is working.
Please check out our [pricing here](http://docs.oraclize.it/#call-fees).

This applies to testnets and local networks as well - of course there coins have no value, but we charge them anyway so that you can test the same pricing logic you have on the mainnet!